# IPtables - Sensible and non-contradictory rules?

Tags: linux, security, debian, iptables

This is my IPtable rules for my webserver with SSH installed, i've had help to get this far. My question is, are my rules contradictory. For example, I've been recommended to use these two lines:

```
# DONT KNOW WHAT THESE DO
$i -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$i -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
```

But in my overall script I feel that they may not be actually doing anything.

```
i=/sbin/iptables

# Flush all rules
$i -F
$i -X

# Setup default filter policy
$i -P INPUT DROP
$i -P OUTPUT DROP
$i -P FORWARD DROP

# DONT KNOW WHAT THESE DO
$i -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$i -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT

# Force SYN checks
$i -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP

# Drop all fragments
$i -A INPUT -f -j DROP

# Drop XMAS packets
$i -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP

# Drop NULL packets
$i -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP

# Allow established connections
$i -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow unlimited traffic on loopback
$i -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$i -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Open nginx
$i -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
$i -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

# Open SSH
$i -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I think it's time you learned to read the documentation, it's really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first of these accepts all traffic on the loopback interface.  This is one of the ways the kernel talks to itself, and it's fairly important not to block this traffic; unpredictable results can occur if you do.  It is a standard rule and I'm not aware of any security implications to using it.

The second is a little more complex.  There are a number of types of ICMP that you want to permit, either for informational (eg ICMP-host-unreachable) or functional (eg ICMP-fragmentation-needed, ICMP-echo-reply) purposes.  But there are others, such as ICMP-echo-request, that you may not want to permit.  There is no easy way to advise you on what you should do, but some might argue that

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

was a little less permissive, and preserved nearly all the useful functionality.

That all said, I note you list the loopback rule **twice**, which is completely pointless, and you are filtering `OUTPUT` traffic and permitting no return-half packets to the permitted `INPUT` traffic.  So that's not going to work at all well.

I'm afraid I have to agree with Iain; if you want to start customising your `iptables` rules you need to learn quite a bit more about TCP/IP before doing so.

Answer (score 1):

A likely reason for adding such rules at the top of your INPUT chain is to accept the packages early, so that they won't have to traverse all your rules:

```
$i -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT # whitelist all loopback traffic
$i -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT # whitelist all ICMP traffic
```

To find out how much use individual rules see, use

```
iptables -L -nv
```